# Android need help with nine-patch tool to stretch image horizontally

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

Can someone explain to me how to prepare a PNG image as a nine-patch for Android?  I don't believe that the Android link (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) is helpful enough.  Here is my image that I want to stretch horizontally:

[image]

When I add the image to the nine-patch tool, there is really no option for me to draw any black lines.  So then I added blank pixels around the image, and added black lines, which generated the following nine-patch:

[image]

If somebody could explain to me, or perhaps show me how to prepare my PNG to stretch horizontally, I'd really appreciate it...

Comment: i think you should accept answers for question you have asked in past. It will improve your reputation and more and more people would love to answer you in future.